# Angle of the Sun during winter solstice

Tags: the-sun, earth

What is the angle of the Sun on the eastern horizon at 35° latitude if it is the winter solstice?

Comment: If the Sun is "on the eastern horizon" then the altitude is zero. Perhaps you mean "azimuth?"

Comment: This is the way the problem worded it, but yes, Azimuth would make sense in the context of this.

Comment: Okay thanks! Well then you need to decide which one you'd like answered here in Stack Exchange. If it's altitude, then I think you can answer your own question here by clicking the Answer button. But if you want Azimuth answered here, then you can click "edit" and change to azimuth.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to insta-close this question so quickly, the OP is responsive and working to clarify.

Comment: winter in Northern or Southern Hemisphere?